# HP Elitebook 8470W internal component with buttons - what does it do?

Tags: laptop, components

I spilled a glass of juice on my laptop, which is a problem in and of itself but I'm up to that task.  However when I took the bottom off the laptop with a view to simplifying the cleaning process, I found there was a separate modular component at the front of the layout connected to the main board by power wires.  This was the only connection.  The module had two "soft" buttons on it.  Buttons which obviously could not be accessed when the computer was assembled. I've looked through what manuals I could find and haven't found this described.  Can anyone tell me what it is, what it's for and what the buttons do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture?

Comment: Clearly it's a battery, I'd guess the CMOS one - but with two buttons?

Comment: Obviously a batter, probably the CMOS one, but the two buttons do what?  And if I can figure out how post an image, I shall...

Comment: ![IMG_20161212_134942.jpg](https://postimg.org/image/hpla0g2xr/)
![IMG_20161212_135126.jpg](https://postimg.org/image/awu3q04lz/)
![IMG_20161212_135141.jpg](https://postimg.org/image/tb10cfvyx/)

Comment: It looks like speakers to me.

Answer (score 2):

They're speakers.

As per the fine service manual -[which you can find here](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03659338-3.pdf) - its part number 641840-001 and you can find it in page 94

Those 'buttons' appear to be square speakers made by [vansonic/Veco](http://www.veco.com.tw/cgi-bin/product-search.cgi?template=report-speaker&dbname=product&f4=Enhanced&f5=Active&exactmatch=f7&f7=Square%20Speakers&sortfield=f6&sorttype=alpha-ascend&action=searchdbdisplay) - if you needed to go beyond mere curiocity, you can likely find the exact model based on size.
Those arn't buttons, and you don't want to push on them.

Comment: Here's the correct manual: http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03659338-3.pdf. The speaker assembly on this manual (pg. 94) also matches the one pictured. The spare part number is 641840-001.

Comment: Fixed ;p - I literally had a dyslexic moment with the model numbers

Comment: Brilliant!  I don't usually associate laptops with speakers or I would've figured that out.  Thank you peeps, at least I learned how to post images...

Comment: Service manuals are awesome even when you know what you're doing. HP actually does a very good job at making them available, even if they're a little known resource.